# accept is not working in file type in react

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, file, user-interface

I am creating a file upload component in which I have to allow only `xls` or `xlsx` file.I am writing below code.

```
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="file" accept="xlsx/*" required  onChange={handleChange}/>
          <button type="submit" className='submitbutton'>Import Bulk User</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

but it is not restricting other file types.

[image]

how can I restrict other file types and allow only `xlsx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [accept attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept) takes as its value a comma-separated list of one or more file types, or unique file type specifiers, describing which file types to allow:

```
<input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" required  onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - this time I improved the answer for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You could still use your handler function to validate the file extension.

Get the file extension by

```
 event.target.files[0].name.split(".")[1];
```

and then check if its supported or not

```
if (allowedExtension.includes(fileExtension)) {
    console.info("correct file uploaded!");
    // set file to state
    setUploadedFile(file);
} else {
    console.error("incorrect file extension");
    // show error
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/validate-file-extension-8bnhti?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

You should update your input's `accept` attribute as below:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" required  onChange={handleChange}/>
```

More about accept: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept